# Helps with footer html css

Tags: html, css

I bought a course, There is a lesson on the course, and I have a problem with the `<div>` with the footer class. I have it on top, but it should be on the bottom of the video. When writing the code, he had no problems, I just happened. I am attaching the code and screenshots.

**I have it wrong**

[image]

**it should be**

[image]

Code html:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #555;
}

p {
  padding: 0 0 20px 0;
  line-height: 1.7em;
}

input[type="text"],
input[type="password"],
input[type="search"] {
  color: #5d5d5d;
  width: 60%;
  padding: 8px;
}

input,
textarea {
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  border: solid 1px #f2f2f2;
}

h1,
h2 {
  font: normal 170% 'century gothic', arial;
  margin: 0 0 15px 0;
  padding: 15px 0 5px 0;
  color: #000;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 140%
}

a,
a:hover {
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: green;
}

ul {
  margin: 2px 0 22px 17px;
}

ul li {
  margin: 0 0 6px 0;
  padding: 0 0 4px 5px;
  line-height: #000;
}

.header {
  background-color: darkslateblue;
  height: 177px;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  min-width: auto;
}

.mine,
.logo,
.menubar,
.site_content,
.footer {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.logo {
  width: 880px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.logo h1,
.logo h2 {
  font: normal 300% 'century gothic', arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 0 0 0 9px;
}

.logo_text h1,
.logo_text h1 a,
.logo_text h1 a:hover {
  padding: 22px 0 0 0;
  color: #fff;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.logo_text h2 {
  font-size: 0.9em;
  padding: 4px 0 0 0;
  color: #999;
}

.menubar {
  width: 950px;
  height: 46px;
}

ul.menu {
  float: right;
}

ul.menu li {
  float: left;
  padding: 0 0 0 9px;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 1px 2px 0 0;
}

ul.menu li a {
  font: normal 100% 'trebuchet ms', sans-serif;
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 6px 35px 6px 28px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul.menu li.selected a {
  color: #aeb002;
}

ul.menu li a:hover {
  color: #e4ec04;
}

.site_content {
  width: 880px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
  background-color: white;
}

.sidebar_containter {
  float: right;
  width: 224px;
}

.sidebar {
  float: right;
  widows: 222px;
  padding: 5%;
  margin: 0 0 16px 0;
  border: solid 1px #f2f2f2;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}

.btn {
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.sidebar h2 {
  color: #136cb2;
}

.lables_passreg_text {
  font-size: 0.7em;
  margin-top: 3%;
  margin-left: 2%;
}

.sitebar ul {
  margin: 0;
}

.sitebar ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
}

.sitebar .rating_sidebar {
  float: right;
}

.footer {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: darkslateblue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="description" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="asset\css\style.css">
  <title>K.S</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="header">
      <div class="logo">
        <div class="logo_text">
          <h1><a href="/">KinoStar</a></h1>
          <h2>Кино - только для вас!</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="menubar">
        <ul class="menu">
          <li class="selected"><a href="#">Главная</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Фильмы</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Сериалы</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Рейтинг Фильмов</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="site_content">
        <div class="sidebar_containter">
          <div class="sidebar">
           <h2>Поиск</h2>
            <form method="post" action="#" id="search_form">
              <input type="search" name="search_field" placeholder="ваш запрос" />
              <input type="submit" class="btn" value="найти">
            </form>
          </div>
          <div class="sidebar">
            <h2>Вход</h2>
            <form method="post" action="#" id="login">
              <input type="text" name="login_field" placeholder="логин" />
              <input type="password" name="password_field" placeholder="пароль" />
              <input type="submit" class="btn" value="вход" />
              <div class="lables_passreg_text">
                <span></span><a href="#">забыл пароль?</a><span></span>|<span></span><a href="#">регистрация</a><span></span>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
          <div class="sidebar">
            <h2>Новости</h2>
            <span>31.10.2020</span>
            <p>Запуск сайта на тестовом хостинге.</p>
            <a href="#">Читать</a>
          </div>
          <div class="sidebar">
            <h2>Рейтинг фильмов</h2>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Наруто</a><span class="rating_sidebar"> 10</span></li>
              <li><a href="#">Dxd</a><span class="rating_sidebar"> 9.9</span></li>
              <li><a href="#">Убица гоблинов</a><span class="rating_sidebar"> 9.9</span></li>
              <li><a href="#">Моя геройская академия</a><span class="rating_sidebar"> 9.9</span></li>
              <li><a href="#">Шаман Кинг</a><span class="rating_sidebar"> 9.9</span></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
      <p>
        <a href="#">Главная</a> |
        <a href="#">Фильмы</a> |
        <a href="#">Сериалы</a> |
        <a href="#">Рейтинг</a> |
        <a href="#">Контакты</a>
      </p>
      <p>kn-st.com 2020</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is at least one problem: The line `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="asset\css\style.css">` should be `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="asset/css/style.css">`

Comment: Also you need some content between the header and footer

Comment: nor is it a dumb problem I have a problem with the css code itself

Comment: I'm from Ukraine. I study the course and the teacher is fine and I do not. The code is the same. And I can't turn to him.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple things wrong in your code. For starters, the way you have mentioned css in link tag is wrong.
This should be the correct way -

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="asset/css/style.css">
```

Secondly, you wrote footer as a class for a div. Footer is an actual tag in html which is used for writing footer. I changed the entire <div class="footer", to just `<footer>`.

Third, you wrote all the code in header class itself. Which means footer is never reached. So you need to keep header only till the header part, yet you included all of the sidemenu and footer in it.

I changed the code, copy paste and try it now

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #555;
}

p {
  padding: 0 0 20px 0;
  line-height: 1.7em;
}

input[type="text"],
input[type="password"],
input[type="search"] {
  color: #5d5d5d;
  width: 60%;
  padding: 8px;
}

input,
textarea {
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  border: solid 1px #f2f2f2;
}

h1,
h2 {
  font: normal 170% 'century gothic', arial;
  margin: 0 0 15px 0;
  padding: 15px 0 5px 0;
  color: #000;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 140%
}

a,
a:hover {
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: green;
}

ul {
  margin: 2px 0 22px 17px;
}

ul li {
  margin: 0 0 6px 0;
  padding: 0 0 4px 5px;
  line-height: #000;
}

.header {
  background-color: darkslateblue;
  height: 177px;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  min-width: auto;
}

.mine,
.logo,
.menubar,
.site_content,
footer {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.logo {
  width: 880px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.logo h1,
.logo h2 {
  font: normal 300% 'century gothic', arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 0 0 0 9px;
}

.logo_text h1,
.logo_text h1 a,
.logo_text h1 a:hover {
  padding: 22px 0 0 0;
  color: #fff;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.logo_text h2 {
  font-size: 0.9em;
  padding: 4px 0 0 0;
  color: #999;
}

.menubar {
  width: 950px;
  height: 46px;
}

ul.menu {
  float: right;
}

ul.menu li {
  float: left;
  padding: 0 0 0 9px;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 1px 2px 0 0;
}

ul.menu li a {
  font: normal 100% 'trebuchet ms', sans-serif;
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 6px 35px 6px 28px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul.menu li.selected a {
  color: #aeb002;
}

ul.menu li a:hover {
  color: #e4ec04;
}

.site_content {
  width: 880px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
  background-color: white;
}

.sidebar_containter {
  float: right;
  width: 224px;
}

.sidebar {
  float: right;
  widows: 222px;
  padding: 5%;
  margin: 0 0 16px 0;
  border: solid 1px #f2f2f2;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}

.btn {
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.sidebar h2 {
  color: #136cb2;
}

.lables_passreg_text {
  font-size: 0.7em;
  margin-top: 3%;
  margin-left: 2%;
}

.sitebar ul {
  margin: 0;
}

.sitebar ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
}

.sitebar .rating_sidebar {
  float: right;
}

footer {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: darkslateblue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="description" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="asset/css/style.css">
  <title>K.S</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="header">
      <div class="logo">
        <div class="logo_text">
          <h1><a href="/">KinoStar</a></h1>
          <h2>Кино - только для вас!</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="menubar">
        <ul class="menu">
          <li class="selected"><a href="#">Главная</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Фильмы</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Сериалы</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Рейтинг Фильмов</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="site_content">
      <div class="sidebar_containter">
        <div class="sidebar">
          <h2>Поиск</h2>
          <form method="post" action="#" id="search_form">
            <input type="search" name="search_field" placeholder="ваш запрос" />
            <input type="submit" class="btn" value="найти">
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="sidebar">
          <h2>Вход</h2>
          <form method="post" action="#" id="login">
            <input type="text" name="login_field" placeholder="логин" />
            <input type="password" name="password_field" placeholder="пароль" />
            <input type="submit" class="btn" value="вход" />
            <div class="lables_passreg_text">
              <span></span><a href="#">забыл пароль?</a><span></span>|<span></span><a href="#">регистрация</a><span></span>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="sidebar">
          <h2>Новости</h2>
          <span>31.10.2020</span>
          <p>Запуск сайта на тестовом хостинге.</p>
          <a href="#">Читать</a>
        </div>
        <div class="sidebar">
          <h2>Рейтинг фильмов</h2>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Наруто</a><span class="rating_sidebar"> 10</span></li>
            <li><a href="#">Dxd</a><span class="rating_sidebar"> 9.9</span></li>
            <li><a href="#">Убица гоблинов</a><span class="rating_sidebar"> 9.9</span></li>
            <li><a href="#">Моя геройская академия</a><span class="rating_sidebar"> 9.9</span></li>
            <li><a href="#">Шаман Кинг</a><span class="rating_sidebar"> 9.9</span></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer>
    <p>
      <a href="#">Главная</a> |
      <a href="#">Фильмы</a> |
      <a href="#">Сериалы</a> |
      <a href="#">Рейтинг</a> |
      <a href="#">Контакты</a>
    </p>
    <p>kn-st.com 2020</p>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: OP is following a course. He put the content inside the header. That is the biggest error - I am not saying the comments you have are not relevant, but that was not the actual issue

Comment: It worked. Thank you.Now I will understand what and how it was changed. And thank you every time

Comment: Don't you think using footer makes more sense then just <div class="footer">. Since, he is following a course, its important to tell all the mistakes.

Comment: Since he is following a course, you should not confuse him since the rest of the course may not make any sense if you change the HTML

Comment: I don't know, I found this course. And you listen to memorizes and did as he shows

Comment: Choose an answer and close your question if solved OP.

Comment: I have a question whether you can use <div class = "footer"> or not

Comment: By html format, you should not use <div class ="footer">. There is a separate tag just for footer, you should use that. I have used the same in my code. So, professionally use <footer> /<footer>

Answer (score 1):

Your `.site_content` div is inside of the header. It should be after that and before the footer like this:

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="header">...</div>
    <div class="site_content">...</div>
    <div class="footer">...</div>
</div>
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #555;
}

p {
  padding: 0 0 20px 0;
  line-height: 1.7em;
}

input[type="text"],
input[type="password"],
input[type="search"] {
  color: #5d5d5d;
  width: 60%;
  padding: 8px;
}

input,
textarea {
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  border: solid 1px #f2f2f2;
}

h1,
h2 {
  font: normal 170% 'century gothic', arial;
  margin: 0 0 15px 0;
  padding: 15px 0 5px 0;
  color: #000;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 140%
}

a,
a:hover {
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: green;
}

ul {
  margin: 2px 0 22px 17px;
}

ul li {
  margin: 0 0 6px 0;
  padding: 0 0 4px 5px;
  line-height: #000;
}

.header {
  background-color: darkslateblue;
  height: 177px;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  min-width: auto;
}

.mine,
.logo,
.menubar,
.site_content,
.footer {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.logo {
  width: 880px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.logo h1,
.logo h2 {
  font: normal 300% 'century gothic', arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 0 0 0 9px;
}

.logo_text h1,
.logo_text h1 a,
.logo_text h1 a:hover {
  padding: 22px 0 0 0;
  color: #fff;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.logo_text h2 {
  font-size: 0.9em;
  padding: 4px 0 0 0;
  color: #999;
}

.menubar {
  width: 950px;
  height: 46px;
}

ul.menu {
  float: right;
}

ul.menu li {
  float: left;
  padding: 0 0 0 9px;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 1px 2px 0 0;
}

ul.menu li a {
  font: normal 100% 'trebuchet ms', sans-serif;
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 6px 35px 6px 28px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul.menu li.selected a {
  color: #aeb002;
}

ul.menu li a:hover {
  color: #e4ec04;
}

.site_content {
  width: 880px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
  background-color: white;
}

.sidebar_containter {
  float: right;
  width: 224px;
}

.sidebar {
  float: right;
  widows: 222px;
  padding: 5%;
  margin: 0 0 16px 0;
  border: solid 1px #f2f2f2;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}

.btn {
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.sidebar h2 {
  color: #136cb2;
}

.lables_passreg_text {
  font-size: 0.7em;
  margin-top: 3%;
  margin-left: 2%;
}

.sitebar ul {
  margin: 0;
}

.sitebar ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
}

.sitebar .rating_sidebar {
  float: right;
}

.footer {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: darkslateblue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="description" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="asset\css\style.css">
  <title>K.S</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="header">
      <div class="logo">
        <div class="logo_text">
          <h1><a href="/">KinoStar</a></h1>
          <h2>Кино - только для вас!</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="menubar">
        <ul class="menu">
          <li class="selected"><a href="#">Главная</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Фильмы</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Сериалы</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Рейтинг Фильмов</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="site_content">
      <div class="sidebar_containter">
        <div class="sidebar">
          <h2>Поиск</h2>
          <form method="post" action="#" id="search_form">
            <input type="search" name="search_field" placeholder="ваш запрос" />
            <input type="submit" class="btn" value="найти">
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="sidebar">
          <h2>Вход</h2>
          <form method="post" action="#" id="login">
            <input type="text" name="login_field" placeholder="логин" />
            <input type="password" name="password_field" placeholder="пароль" />
            <input type="submit" class="btn" value="вход" />
            <div class="lables_passreg_text">
              <span></span><a href="#">забыл пароль?</a><span></span>|<span></span><a href="#">регистрация</a><span></span>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="sidebar">
          <h2>Новости</h2>
          <span>31.10.2020</span>
          <p>Запуск сайта на тестовом хостинге.</p>
          <a href="#">Читать</a>
        </div>
        <div class="sidebar">
          <h2>Рейтинг фильмов</h2>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Наруто</a><span class="rating_sidebar"> 10</span></li>
            <li><a href="#">Dxd</a><span class="rating_sidebar"> 9.9</span></li>
            <li><a href="#">Убица гоблинов</a><span class="rating_sidebar"> 9.9</span></li>
            <li><a href="#">Моя геройская академия</a><span class="rating_sidebar"> 9.9</span></li>
            <li><a href="#">Шаман Кинг</a><span class="rating_sidebar"> 9.9</span></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
      <p>
        <a href="#">Главная</a> |
        <a href="#">Фильмы</a> |
        <a href="#">Сериалы</a> |
        <a href="#">Рейтинг</a> |
        <a href="#">Контакты</a>
      </p>
      <p>kn-st.com 2020</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: As I commented. Well spotted

Answer (score 0):

Remove height from header class

```
.header {
    background-color: darkslateblue;
    /* height: 177px; */ Remove this line
    font-size: 0.8em;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    min-width: auto;
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #555;
}

p {
  padding: 0 0 20px 0;
  line-height: 1.7em;
}

input[type="text"],
input[type="password"],
input[type="search"] {
  color: #5d5d5d;
  width: 60%;
  padding: 8px;
}

input,
textarea {
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  border: solid 1px #f2f2f2;
}

h1,
h2 {
  font: normal 170% 'century gothic', arial;
  margin: 0 0 15px 0;
  padding: 15px 0 5px 0;
  color: #000;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 140%
}

a,
a:hover {
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: green;
}

ul {
  margin: 2px 0 22px 17px;
}

ul li {
  margin: 0 0 6px 0;
  padding: 0 0 4px 5px;
  line-height: #000;
}

.header {
  background-color: darkslateblue;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  min-width: auto;
}

.mine,
.logo,
.menubar,
.site_content,
.footer {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.logo {
  width: 880px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.logo h1,
.logo h2 {
  font: normal 300% 'century gothic', arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 0 0 0 9px;
}

.logo_text h1,
.logo_text h1 a,
.logo_text h1 a:hover {
  padding: 22px 0 0 0;
  color: #fff;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.logo_text h2 {
  font-size: 0.9em;
  padding: 4px 0 0 0;
  color: #999;
}

.menubar {
  width: 950px;
  height: 46px;
}

ul.menu {
  float: right;
}

ul.menu li {
  float: left;
  padding: 0 0 0 9px;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 1px 2px 0 0;
}

ul.menu li a {
  font: normal 100% 'trebuchet ms', sans-serif;
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 6px 35px 6px 28px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul.menu li.selected a {
  color: #aeb002;
}

ul.menu li a:hover {
  color: #e4ec04;
}

.site_content {
  width: 880px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
  background-color: white;
}

.sidebar_containter {
  float: right;
  width: 224px;
}

.sidebar {
  float: right;
  widows: 222px;
  padding: 5%;
  margin: 0 0 16px 0;
  border: solid 1px #f2f2f2;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}

.btn {
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.sidebar h2 {
  color: #136cb2;
}

.lables_passreg_text {
  font-size: 0.7em;
  margin-top: 3%;
  margin-left: 2%;
}

.sitebar ul {
  margin: 0;
}

.sitebar ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
}

.sitebar .rating_sidebar {
  float: right;
}

.footer {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: darkslateblue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="description" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="asset\css\style.css">
  <title>K.S</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="header">
      <div class="logo">
        <div class="logo_text">
          <h1><a href="/">KinoStar</a></h1>
          <h2>Кино - только для вас!</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="menubar">
        <ul class="menu">
          <li class="selected"><a href="#">Главная</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Фильмы</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Сериалы</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Рейтинг Фильмов</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="site_content">
        <div class="sidebar_containter">
          <div class="sidebar">
           <h2>Поиск</h2>
            <form method="post" action="#" id="search_form">
              <input type="search" name="search_field" placeholder="ваш запрос" />
              <input type="submit" class="btn" value="найти">
            </form>
          </div>
          <div class="sidebar">
            <h2>Вход</h2>
            <form method="post" action="#" id="login">
              <input type="text" name="login_field" placeholder="логин" />
              <input type="password" name="password_field" placeholder="пароль" />
              <input type="submit" class="btn" value="вход" />
              <div class="lables_passreg_text">
                <span></span><a href="#">забыл пароль?</a><span></span>|<span></span><a href="#">регистрация</a><span></span>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
          <div class="sidebar">
            <h2>Новости</h2>
            <span>31.10.2020</span>
            <p>Запуск сайта на тестовом хостинге.</p>
            <a href="#">Читать</a>
          </div>
          <div class="sidebar">
            <h2>Рейтинг фильмов</h2>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Наруто</a><span class="rating_sidebar"> 10</span></li>
              <li><a href="#">Dxd</a><span class="rating_sidebar"> 9.9</span></li>
              <li><a href="#">Убица гоблинов</a><span class="rating_sidebar"> 9.9</span></li>
              <li><a href="#">Моя геройская академия</a><span class="rating_sidebar"> 9.9</span></li>
              <li><a href="#">Шаман Кинг</a><span class="rating_sidebar"> 9.9</span></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
      <p>
        <a href="#">Главная</a> |
        <a href="#">Фильмы</a> |
        <a href="#">Сериалы</a> |
        <a href="#">Рейтинг</a> |
        <a href="#">Контакты</a>
      </p>
      <p>kn-st.com 2020</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The content is inside the header. That is the issue